# switching between style display while navigating views

Tags: display

I have 3 partial views that'll act as the chain of modal popups. the first partial view 'A' while drawing as a modal, its style is set to display: none. however after navigating past 'A' to 'B' i have an option to return to 'A'. when i click back on 'B', 'A' draws up as a modal with just white space instead of redrawing its contents. I know its because the display is set to none. but if i remove that style, then 'A' while called for the first time it acts weird like the page jumps a bit before the modal popups up.

I need a solution that would help me reset the style only when the view is draw while clicking back.

hope i am not confusing..